# matching fewer than all fields with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a MongoDB query that looks like this:

```
result = db.collection.find(
    {
        'fruit_type': 'apple', 
        'fruit_name': 'macintosh' 
        'primary_color': 'red', 
        'sheen': 'glossy', 
        'origin_label': 'true', 
        'stem_present': 'true', 
        'stem_leaves_present': 'true', 
        'blemish': 'none', 
        'firmness': 'moderate'
    }
)
```

When I have exact matches, I want only the exact matches. When I don't have exact matches, then (and only then) I want other apples, with the only mandatory fields and values being `'fruit_type': 'apple'` and `'primary_color': 'red'`.

Note: this question has been edited multiple times for clarity

Comment: Drive-by downvotes are not useful. Please explain why this is a bad question.

Comment: I can only guess, but some people tend to see JavaScript as no real programming language. ;) Personally, I think it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can be to ensure that you at least satisfy the mandatory criteria is to put all your optional query fields together with one of the mandatory fields in the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator since it selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the optional expressions in the $or operator expression:

```
result = db.collection.find(
    {
        'fruit_type': 'apple',                       
        "$or": [ 
            { 'primary_color': 'red' },
            { 'fruit_name': 'macintosh' }, 
            { 'sheen': 'glossy' }, 
            { 'origin_label': 'true' }, 
            { 'stem_present': 'true' }, 
            { 'stem_leaves_present': 'true' }, 
            { 'blemish': 'none' }, 
            { 'firmness': 'moderate' }
        ]
    }
)
```

The above query will select all documents in the collection where the fruit_type field value is apple and the `primary_color` field value equals red. If in your collection there is no document with the `primary_color` field value as red then the above will not return any documents.

Performance-wise, consider creating a compound index on the two mandatory fields if they are the commonly issued queries since scanning an index is much faster than scanning a collection.

For more details, read the docs sections on **[Optimize Query Performance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/)** and **[Behaviors - $or Clauses and Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#behaviors)**

Comment: @bahmait Ok, have you tested the query above?

Comment: @bahmait Cheers for the clarification. In your first edit your question was rather unclear and I answered based on the premise that you need to include two mandatory fields in your query, the above just does that; it returns a match if at least the two mandatory fields match.

Comment: I've accepted the answer finally, and tried to clarify again. I think what I wanted was to say basically: exact match OR inexact match.